# How to create classes in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

```
D               E           F
772597          49.36.00    30316
746554          39.33.00    35820
976942          44.46.00    142864
1075820         41.33.00    93708
```

My dataset needs to be simplified, by that I mean turning numbers into classifications. 
For example value less or equal to 99 = 1. 100-999 = 2. 1000-1999 = 3, etc.

I got this code for a column and it works great:

```
=ArrayFormula(1*(B2:B900*1,05<B3:B900))
```

But the data in the other columns in the dataset needs to be turned into numeric classes.

I need a formula that transforms the data in column D to be replaced with 1, 2, 3... and same with the data in the other columns

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471

Answer (score 1):

try nesting it:

```
=IF(AND(D1>0;     D1<100);   1;
 IF(AND(D1>=100;  D1<1000);  2;
 IF(AND(D1>=1000; D1<2000);  3; )))
```

Comment: Thx, @player0
I tried this:

=IF(AND(D:D>=1; D:D<=1000000); 1; IF(AND(D:D>=1000001; D:D<=10000000); 2; IF(AND(D:D>=10000001; D:D<=100000000); 3;)))

But it did not return anything, no error either.

Answer (score 0):

For Numeric columns, please try the likes of:

```
=ArrayFormula(floor(log(D1:D))--(D1:D<10))
```